# command not found when run with sudo

Tags: command-line, permissions, dpkg, sudo

I installed TexLive 2021, and set my PATH by updating the `~/.bashrc` file. So I can run all commands, but not with `sudo`:

```bsh
~$ tlmgr install book
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2021/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
~$ sudo tlmgr install book
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

How can that be?

Comment: ... presumably because the location of `tlmgr` is not on the sudoers `secure_path`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't awarre of that `secure_path`. I quickly found how to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the full path of `tlmgr`, i.e.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/tlmgr install book
```

Adjust the path to your setting.